# Basic questions on javascript 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Could anyone help figure out why the `onclick` event does not trigger when I click the button.

I directly insert a function inside the code, rather than ref an external .js file.

And, when click the button, more text will be displayed. The inner text of the button will be 'Read less'. After clicking the button again, text will be hidden, and the inner text of the button will be 'Read more'.

I am so confused.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Form Validation:)</title>
  <!-- <script src="recreative.js"></script> -->
  <style>
    #moreText {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  The history of Chemistry represents
  <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="moreText">a time span from ancients history to the present.</span>
  <button id="button" onclick="show();">Read more</button>

  <script>
    function show() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("moreText");
      var btn = document.getElementById("button");

      if (dots.style.display = "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btn.innerHTML = "Read more";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btn.innerHTML = "Read less";
        moreText.style.display = "in line";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using `=`, which is a [`Assignment Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment).
To compare two values either use [`Equal Operator (==)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment) or the [`Strict equal Operator (===)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment)

In the condition of the `if-else` statement, i.e.

```js
if (dots.style.display === "none")
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Form Validation:)</title>
  <!-- <script src="recreative.js"></script> -->
  <style>
    #moreText {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  The history of Chemistry represents
  <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="moreText">a time span from ancients history to the present.</span>
  <button id="button" onclick="show();">Read more</button>

  <script>
    function show() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("moreText");
      var btn = document.getElementById("button");

      if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btn.innerHTML = "Read more";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btn.innerHTML = "Read less";
        moreText.style.display = "in line";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the statement that is causing the issue: `if (dots.style.display = "none")`.

Run this statement in your chrome console: `dots.style.display = "none"`. It returns "none".

```js
if("none"){ console.log("hello"); }
```

Hence, always the first block is executed. And your second else block is of no use.

You need `dots.style.display == "none"`, which is used to **compare values** for equality.

Answer (score 0):

there is some problem in your code

first in IF Statement you assign value, you should check the value with "==" or "==="

second, in `moreText.style.display = "in line";` there is an extra space write "inline"

you should start debugging by write log console, try track and trace the program
Good Luck

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Form Validation:)</title>
    <!-- <script src="recreative.js"></script> -->
    <style>
        #moreText {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    The history of Chemistry represents
    <span id="dots">...</span>
    <span id="moreText">a time span from ancients history to the present.</span>
    <button id="button" onclick="show();">Read more</button>

    <script>
        function show() {
            var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
            var moreText = document.getElementById("moreText");
            var btn = document.getElementById("button");

            if (dots.style.display == "none") {
                dots.style.display = "inline";
                btn.innerHTML = "Read more";
                moreText.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                dots.style.display = "none";
                btn.innerHTML = "Read less";
                moreText.style.display = "inline";
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The use of `=` in if condition was wrong also the logic was also wrong thats why that why the text was not displaying**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Form Validation:)</title>
  <!-- <script src="recreative.js"></script> -->
  <style>
    #moreText {
      display: none;
    }
    #dots{
    display:inline;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  The history of Chemistry represents
  <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="moreText">a time span from ancients history to the present.</span>
  <button id="button" onclick="show();">Read more</button>

  <script>
    function show() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("moreText");
      var btn = document.getElementById("button");

      if (dots.style.display == "inline") {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btn.innerHTML = "Read less";
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btn.innerHTML = "Read more";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you check statement with `=` operator but, you must use `==` operator for compare statement.

so just change this line

```
if (dots.style.display = "none")
```

to this

```
if (dots.style.display == "none")
```

another change you should do. we have not `in line` display. so change it to `inline`

with this, your problem will solve. but i have two **suggest**.

---

**first** use `addEventListener` for your events such as: click, mouseover, etc

this example with `addEventListener` become:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', 'show');
```

or another method is

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){  });
```

**second**, use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByName` and etc

so you can replace this code

```
document.getElementById("dots")
```

with this

```
document.querySelector("#dots")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. A bug is that in the `if` you assign a value instead of comparing and another bug is that you use the term `in line` instead of `inline`.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Form Validation:)</title>
  <!-- <script src="recreative.js"></script> -->
  <style>
    #moreText {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  The history of Chemistry represents
  <span id="dots">...</span>
  <span id="moreText">a time span from ancients history to the present.</span>
  <button id="button" onclick="show();">Read more</button>

  <script>
    function show() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("moreText");
      var btn = document.getElementById("button");

      if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btn.innerHTML = "Read more";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btn.innerHTML = "Read less";
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```